# Transfer multiple textbox values to array

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I have a userform with 13 textboxes from which I'm trying to transfer the values of the last 10 (ie #4-#13) into an array. My thinking was to cycle through all controls on the form and use a simple counter to skip the first 3 textboxes, then set my array elements to the rest of the textbox values in turn.

```
For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(Ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
        i = i + 1
        If i > 3 Then
            PO(i - 3) = Ctrl.Value
        End If
    End If
Next Ctrl
```

The concept itself works; however, the cycle starts with textbox #3 instead of #1, and I end up getting the following values in my array - (#6-#13, #1, #2).  So, the first textbox control it is finding is #3, then going through to #13 and coming back to #1 and #2.

The boxes are named (and tab indexed) in the logical order to fit what I'm trying to do, but obviously there is something about this procedure that I don't quite get - or VBA gets it in a different way than I do.

Is it possible that the `For Each Ctrl` statement goes through controls in the order in which they were originally created, rather than the order of the tabindex or name?  If so, how could I find the original order of creation?

Comment: Are they named Textbox1 etc?

Comment: Are you using `Option Base 1`, or how did you `ReDim` your array? Because it looks like you're assigning your first array value to position 1.

Comment: They are named Textbox1 through Textbox13, and my array is previously dimmed 1 to 10 - hence, skipping the first 3 before starting to transfer values.  I wish to skip Textbox1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this, using the consistent structure of the controls' names.

```
For i = 4 To 13
    PO(i - 3) = Me.Controls("Textbox" & i).Value
Next i
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  I did not know the Controls(Name) syntax.   Would still like to know how the version I used actually searches through the control list.

Comment: My pleasure. I think it might be the order in which they are placed on the form. You could test it by setting up a new form and adding a few controls.